# Can't upload PDF file to PHP Database

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdf

I'm new in the World of programming and I'm doing a PHP project where I'm trying to learn how to upload a pdf file to database. My goal is to insert name of the file (title) and pdf file. For some reason on database (phpmyadmin) it registers name of the file and it save a pdf file. I can't seem to find a solution it would mean a lot to me if you could help me.
This is what I've got:

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{

$title=$_POST['title'];
$pdf=$_POST['pdf'];
$folder = "./pdf/".$filename;
$sql="INSERT INTO  tblfiles(title,pdf) VALUES(:title,:pdf)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':title',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':pdf',$pdf,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

if($lastInsertId)
{
$_SESSION['msg']="File added sucessfuly";
header('location:manage-files.php');
}
else 
{
$_SESSION['error']="Error";
header('location:add-files.php');
```

and here is my form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>File name : </label><br>
<input type="text" name="title"><br>
<label>Add file</label>
<input type="File" name="pdf">
<button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info">Add </button>
</form>
```

[Database when I upload the title of pdf and pdf file, you can see in pdf section it says it's NULL, I have it selected as VARCHAR 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkWCh.png)

Thank you so much for your help and sorry for my english

EDIT 1:
Okay so I changed $_POST['pdf']; to $_FILES['pdf']; and changed it from VARCHAR to BLOB and now when I upload a pdf file it saves it as [BLOB - 5 B] and when I click on it it downloads a "bin" file

Comment: Check your tutorial again...uploaded files in PHP go to $_FILES, not $_POST. And usually it's better to save the name of the file in the database, and save the file itself on the disk

Comment: pdf are binary like images so saving must be blobs,

Comment: Okay so I changed $_POST['pdf']; to $_FILES['pdf']; and changed it from VARCHAR to BLOB and now when I upload a pdf file it saves it as [BLOB - 5 B] and when I click on it it downloads a "bin" file

Comment: Where do you click on it? That's unclear.

Comment: Oh sorry, when I go to phpmyadmin to table where file is uploaded. here is a picture: https://ibb.co/1GYncxF

Comment: Ah well phpMyAdmin doesn't know it's supposed to be a PDF, so don't worry about that. Perhaps if you rename it to .pdf after downloading, it would open